# Grails create a service from a factory

Tags: grails, spring-bean

I would like to utilize a service written in Java in my Grails app using dependency injection. Creating it in Java without injection would look like this:

```
ServiceFactory.newInstance().getElementService()
```

I would like to use this in the same way services are injected for controllers, services, and jobs.

```
class ImportJob {
    def elementService
    ...
}
```

I know this should go into `resources.groovy` and this is what I have so far:

```
serviceFactory(ServiceFactory) { bean ->
    bean.factoryMethod = 'newInstance'
}

elementService(ElementService) {

}
```

I have found few resources in the documentation to help with this. How do I complete the elementService so it is creating the object as described above? Should I use a BeanBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bean.factoryMethod` and `bean.factoryBean` in the elementService bean.

```
serviceFactory(ServiceFactory) { bean ->
    bean.factoryMethod = 'newInstance'
    bean.scope = 'singleton'
}

elementService(ElementService) { bean ->
    bean.factoryMethod = 'getElementService'
    bean.factoryBean = 'serviceFactory'
}
```

This is a simple solution especially if ServiceFactory is external and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 5):

You could create a `FactoryBean` for this since it's not as direct as calling a method in a class:

```
package com.mycompany

import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

class ElementServiceFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<ElementService>, InitializingBean {

   private ElementService elementService

   ElementService getObject() { elementService }

   Class<ElementService> getObjectType() { ElementService }

   boolean isSingleton() { true }

   void afterPropertiesSet() {
      elementService = ServiceFactory.newInstance().elementService
   }
}
```

and you'd register it in `resources.groovy` as

```
elementService(ElementServiceFactoryBean)
```

Comment: I like this answer but I still think it should be possible to use ServiceFactory in resources.groovy. The documentation show something called BeanBuilder. Should I use that?

Comment: @JohnMercier - You may be misunderstanding but you can use your `ServiceFactory` in `resources.groovy`.  If that class implements `FactoryBean` then exactly what you have shown in your own example may work (depending on some factors that you haven't described).  It may be that you can just remove your `elementService` bean and rename your `serviceFactory` bean to be `elementService`.   That is how `FactoryBean` beans work.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown ServiceFactory is from a different project which I cannot change. I'm trying to use elementService in my grails project as a dependency injected value. Using ElementServiceFactoryBean works but I'm wondering if there is a way to use ServiceFactory directly in application.groovy instead of wrapping it in the FactoryBean.

Comment: " I'm wondering if there is a way to use ServiceFactory directly in application.groovy instead of wrapping it in the FactoryBean." - @JohnMercier I don't think there is, and I don't think you should.